# Translate magento template from en_US to pt_PT

Tags: magento2, template, translate

I tried the follow:

```
rm -rf vendor/mageplaza/core-m2
rm -rf app/code/Mageplaza/Core
composer remove mageplaza/core-m2
composer dump-autoload
composer require mageplaza/magento-2-portuguese-language-pack:dev-master
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I want to translate my template from en_US to pt_PT. From Magento 2 admin panel, i went to Stores > Configuration > General > Locale Options and I changed to Portuguese. Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute following additional commands , I am pretty sure it due to static content not being deployed for the language and indexes not reindexed.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy pt_PT
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Ping me if it doesn't help.

Comment: I think I identified the issue. The problem was cauded by the fact I was running the app in default mode and deploying the static content without seeing the logs. I followed your instructions step by step and figure out that when I tried to deploy the content with -f parameter it started to give errors deploying my template (luma was ok): 
variable @fa-css-prefix is undefined in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/pt_PT/font-awesome/less/core.less in core.less on line 4, column 2. I don't know how to turn around this issue.

Comment: Wait a second. It's all set for now. I followed the your list. It's all set. Thank you for your help Vivek.

Comment: Please mark the answer accepted if it helped you get to the solution.

Comment: Vivek I succeded the action acting locally in my computer(localhost). I'm replicating the process in my remote server and I just cant have the same result. I don't know waht's missing. Can you help me on this. The language don't change, even following all your steps.

Comment: The steps are same for any kind of environment, please note that I had mentioned the steps to be taken after the steps you had already taken. Please follow the same procedure again and I am sure it will work.

Comment: I tried the same procedure five times with no success. I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: How can I enable the module mageplaza/magento-2-portuguese-language-pack?